# C++/CLI with Pure Mode?

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

I have read in `Foundations of C++ CLI` the following:

> If you try to compile a native C++
>   application with /clr:pure, it will
>   work only if the code being compiled
>   has no constructs that generate
>   machine-specific code. You can,
>   however, link with native libraries.

What is meant by "`constructs that generate machine-specific code`" ? Example?

Also the book says that this mode is not verifiably safe, so we can use pointers for example, now i am confusing in how can say that the compiler will produce pure MSIL code and also we can use pointers! What i know is that, the pointer is somehow native concept! how it will be made as pure MSIL!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSIL is quite powerful, it has no trouble with standard compliant C++03 code.  The only "constructs" I know of that it cannot deal with is the __fastcall calling convention, r-value references as implemented in the C++0x additions in VS2010 and obvious machine specific extensions like the __asm keyword (inline assembly) and intrinsics.

Most any native C++ you compile with /clr in effect will use pointers, either explicitly or compiler-generated to implement things like C++ classes and references.  MSIL has no trouble with it but that code is not verifiable, any MSIL that uses pointers is rejected by the verifier.  This is not necessarily a problem, lots of code runs in full-trust.  You'll only get in trouble when you try to run it on sandboxed execution environments, like a browser, a phone or a game console.  Or when your customer has a nervous system administrator.

Using /clr:pure is otherwise pretty useless.  The point of using C++/CLI is for its great support for interop with native code.  Compiling native code to MSIL is largely a waste, the JIT optimizer can't do as effective a job as the native code optimizer.

Comment: Visual C++ still does a lot more optimization than the C# compiler, even if you throw `/clr:pure`.  Uses for `/clr:pure` would be to create an `AnyCPU` assembly or an assembly that can be loaded into Silverlight.  And saying "the point of using C++/CLI is C++ interop" misses the point, other .NET languages have nothing approaching the power and flexibility of C++ templates.  (generic metaprogramming?  Don't make me laugh.)